# Calling @Html.Partial to display a partial view belonging to a different controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC 3 application, whose content pages have a common pattern of layout elements. However, because the login page does not follow this layout, I cannot place this layout in `\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml`.

So I would like to add another shared layout, say, `\Views\Shared\_Content.cshtml`, and call it from the content views... but unfortunately those views belong to different controllers.

Is there any way to invoke `@Html.Partial` for a view belonging to a different controller?

Comment: Can someone please have the courage to downvote my stupid questions? I can't do it myself.

Comment: You should be able to vote to close your own question. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163375/vote-to-close-own-question

Comment: @pyon I didn't find it stupid at all. It was the first search result to appear based on my Google search query. It's not stupid, just a duplicate.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

That's no problem.

```
@Html.Partial("../Controller/View", model)
```

or

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Controller/View.cshtml", model)
```

Should do the trick.

If you want to pass through the (other) controller, you can use:

```
@Html.Action("action", "controller", parameters)
```

or any of the other overloads

Comment: Why does @Html.Partial("~Views/Controller/View", model) need the .cshtml extension? Otherwise, it says view not found.

Comment: Resharper 6.1 flags `@Html.Partial("../Controller/View", model)` as an error, but not `@Html.Partial("~/Views/Controller/View.cshtml", model)`. Both work fine at runtime.

Comment: @GVs IF windows is using \ for directory then why you use /. Any reason

Comment: @F1betaIndia, I use a azerty-keyboard, to get / I press SHIFT-:, for the \ I have to press AltGr-<. The Shift-: is easier because the key is larger.

Comment: The use of `Html.Action(...)` is ingenious and gets me exactly what I need with the `ChildActionOnlyAttribute` applied to the action.

Comment: @CodeswithHammer I didn't, unfortunately. I just kept the `.cshtml` extension and ran with it.

Comment: If you specify action attributes you must go with `[HttpGet]`

Comment: @ashes999 See Mark Larson's comment right after yours.

Answer (score 7):

As GvS said, but I also find it useful to use [strongly typed views](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC) so that I can write something like

```
@Html.Partial(MVC.Student.Index(), model)
```

without magic strings.

Comment: With Resharper, they don't feel like magic strings anymore :)

Comment: Because of the renaming function?