# Web razor grid in mvc View only works with the type IEnumerable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Good afternoon ...
I'm trying to implement a web grid web grid and call this the partial, but when called and
of a type error sending partial and error type required .. I saw that I looked at the web partial grid is the model that I mandaondo IEnumerable and not IEnumerable ... have some form of change that make the grid work with a web page not IEnumerable?
and another thing when I call a partial view has to be the same type of view?
to call gives a view of another directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking if the view holding your WebGrid needs to be strongly typed with IEnumerable<> then the answer is no. You can pass your collection to WebGrid through ViewBag :

```
controller :

List<MyObject> myList = new List<MyObject>();
// do something with the list
ViewBag.MyCollection = myList;

view:
@{
var grid = new WebGrid(ViewBag.MyCollection);
 }
```

But if you're asking wether WebGrid requires IEnumerable - yes it does, You need to pass a IEnumerable interface implementing object (List<>, Linq result etc. )

To call a partial cross-controllers you can easily do :

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Controller/View", model)
```

take a look at [Calling @Html.Partial to display a partial view belonging to a different controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060397/calling-html-partial-to-display-a-partial-view-belonging-to-a-different-control)

I really hope that I guessed right about your question ...

Comment: the model that is passed along with the partial view has to be the model of veiw? any way to not pass the model?
an example .. when calling the partial run the controller and it just load the grid?